# Trouble rendering dynamically in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I have this function in my react native class:

the Content of Before Button Press shows immediately when the component mounts, but when i press the hello text,the "onPressingTheButton" function is executed and the console shows the logged text and 
the flag is now 2.
the problem is that the "Content After Button Press" is not displayed even after changing the flag.

```
PastEvents = () => {
    var hello;
    var flag = 1

function onPressingTheButton() {
  console.log("logged text")
  flag = 2
  console.log(flag) //2
}
if (flag == 1) {
  hello = <View>Content Before button Press</View> //displayed
}

if (flag == 2) {
   hello = <View>After Button Press</View> //never displayed
}
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {hello}
      <TouchableOpacity>
        <Text onPress={() => onPressingTheButton()}>helloo</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  )
 }
}
```

as a note, the past event function is called by a scenemap from the first render
:

```
 render() {
      return (
        <TabView
          navigationState={{ index: this.state.index, routes: this.state.routes }}
          renderScene={SceneMap({
            PastEvents: this.PastEvents,
            UpcomingEvents: this.UpcomingEvents,
          })}
        />
      );
    }
```

how can I display the "Content After button Press"?
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this you need to use useState like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import {View,Text, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';
import  {useState} from 'react';

PastEvents = () => {
    const [hello , setText] = useState('Before Button Press');
    var flag = 1

    function onPressingTheButton() {
  console.log("logged text")
  flag = 2
  console.log(flag) //2
  if(flag == 2){
    setText('After Button Press');
  }

}

  return (
    <View style={{marginTop:"30%"}}>
      <Text>{hello}</Text>
        <Text onPress={() => onPressingTheButton()}>helloo</Text>
    </View>
  )
 }
 export default PastEvents;
```

[image]

After Button press

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you a lot, it worked for the text, 
but i need it for a View actually.
Is there any way to change a view ?
example 
<VIew>content1</View>
<VIew>content2</View>

Comment: I did of course, but please help me more if you can

Comment: will do,Can you please tell me what's the problem?

Comment: Edited my question. I wrote it in a wrong way my fault. Please check it now and thank you a lot

Comment: I need a view not a text

Comment: you cannot include text inside a view it will given an error saying Text strings must be rendered within a <Text> component

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212344/discussion-between-user12129132-and-alihmede).

Comment: I know , but I want a view with a full content not just text.

Answer (score 0):

Hi can you try to insert the conditional statements into the onPressingTheButton function.

```js
function onPressingTheButton() {
  console.log("logged text")
  flag = 2
  console.log(flag) //2

  if (flag == 1) {
    hello = <Text>Before button Press</Text> //displayed
  }

  if (flag == 2) {
     hello = <Text>After Button Press</Text> //never displayed
  }

}
```